# How many linear arrangements of $5$ A's , $3$ B's , $2$ C's are there with the first $A$ occurring before the first $B$?

Tags: permutations, combinations

How many  linear arrangements of $5$ A's , $3$ B's  , $2$ C's  are there with the first $A$ occurring before the first $B$?

My attempt

Number of arrangements = $\frac {10!}{5!*3!*2!}$=$2520$

But the answer is $1575$

What is wrong with that?

Please elaborate your help as much as possible

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is wrong with the attempt, is that it makes no effort to account for the condition that the first A comes before the first B.

Comment: The number of arrangements of $5$ A's, $3$ B's and $2$ C's where we don't care about anything else is $\frac{10!}{5!3!2!}$.  Several of those however have the first $A$ occurring *after* the first $B$ and should not have been counted, so the number of arrangements that we want to count is strictly less than that.

Comment: @JMoravitz  could you introduce another idea for this problem  please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate way of thinking of this:

First pick which two of the ten positions in the arrangement are occupied by $C$'s.

Then, the first available remaining position must be an $A$.

Finally, arrange the remaining $A$'s and $B$'s in the remaining positions.

Apply multiplication principle (rule of product) and conclude.

> $\binom{10}{2}\cdot \binom{7}{3}$

Comment: fabulous  solution  , thank you very much sir  +1

Answer (score 3):

You should count words starting with $A$, $CA$, and $CCA$, and then add.   The first one, for example, is $$\frac{9!}{4!3!2!}$$

Comment: $ \frac{9!}{4!3!2!} +\frac{8!}{4!3!} +
\frac{7!}{4!3!}$  ?

Answer (score 3):

Ask what the probability is of having the first $A$ before the first $B$.
This is the probability of out of the $A$s and $B$s the first letter is an
$A$. So you are pulling $A$s and $B$s out of an urn; there are five $A$s and three $B$s. The probability the first is an $A$ is $5/8$. So your
answer is $(5/8)\times2520=1575$.